# Using get() when retrieving items with PnP JS Core only return "Undefined" - using items() returns values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-js

First of all, big shout out to the PnP JS guys and gals - great library that I use constantly!

With v2.4.0 I am finding that using the get() call when retrieving items is now returning an "undefined" value, however using the items() call is returning items:

Returns undefined:

```
const items: any[] = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle("Monthly Reports")
  .items.get();
```

returns expected values:

```
const items: any[] = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle("Monthly Reports")
  .items();
```

Why is this?

I want to use the ".get()" call as I want to also call a number of other modifiers, such as:

```
sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle("Monthly Reports")
  .items
  .filter(query)
  .expand("FieldValuesAsText")
  .select(
    "ID",
    "FieldValuesAsText/FileRef",
    "Title"
  )
  .top(5000)
  .orderBy("Modified", false)
  .get()
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably should have shown my pnp setup in the webpart .ts file:
`code
   const { sp } = await import(
      /* webpackChunkName: 'pnp-sp' */
      "@pnp/sp"
    );
    
   // init sp pnpjs library
   sp.setup(this.context);
`
Thanks again

Comment: Should the final call bet `getAll()` not just `get()`?